# How to execute invisible captcha

Tags: javascript, captcha, invisible-recaptcha, hcaptcha

I work with browser automation tool,
I have a problem I get the solution of the captcha but I can not execute the button, the button is invisible, someone may know how to execute it

**I tried to use a few things to make it execute:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button-submit button").submit();

document.getElementsByClassName("button-submit button").onclick();
```

and a few more

**In addition I tried to use a plugin called anycaptcha (https://anycaptcha.com/)**

```
document.getElementById('anycaptchaSolveButton').onclick('Token');
```

I inserted the captcha solution to where I was supposed to insert (* token) and it still did not work for me, I do not know if I did the commands correctly or did execute the wrong thing, I would be happy to help

I tried to do it with form as well and send and still did not work for me.
Form:
[image: Form]

Button-submit button:
[image: Button-submit button]

I'm trying to do it to discord does anyone know how to execute it?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.